# How to use script checkform with session value?

Tags: javascript, php, session

How to use script checkform with session value [ $_SESSION[regis] ]?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkform ( form )
{

  if (form.register.checked == false ) 
  {
    if ($_SESSION[regis]  == "")
        {
            alert( "Please enter check register." );
            form.register.focus();
            return false ;
        }
  }

return true ;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: side note, use of `language="JavaScript"` attribute is considered obsolete

Comment: you cannot use $_SESSION[regis] in javascript. it is php. use it in php tags

Comment: As a side note If your check from function is moved to an external JS file then PHP session value you cant use the way you are doing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't mix javascript variables with php variables. you will at least need to expand it and provide quotes

```
 if ("<?php echo $_SESSION[regis];?>"  == "")
```